# Entity Framework can't keep up with current amount of traffic

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have an asp.net project running on a web server that receives a random amounts of traffic that needs to write this information to a sql database as soon as it receives it. It needs to handle up to 2000 - 3000 messages a second at times and other times just a few a second.

The programmers above me are stuck on using entity framework for the safety it provides, but I can't keep up with the surge of messages sometimes as they need to hit the database fast and can't be queued. The best I've gotten is about 1200 messages a second with entity framework using a save after each request, which I would think is now how entity framework should be used. I know using bulk insert is way more effective, but it isn't an option as we can't hold on to the message as per our requirements given to me. If I do a direct sql insert I can keep up with the message load, but my management says no for the type safety.

Any suggestions on how I can make entity framework keep up with the load or any other frame works that provide the safety and the backing that entity framework has that I bring to management? I've heard dapper is the other good contender, but I have no experience with it to justify it for enterprise solutions.

I've tried researching all the microsoft documents on entity framework and entityframework.net documentation. Tried setting AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false. Everything I read just points to do bulk insert. I've also tried stripping out other tables and have a staging table to see if I can make it faster.

Comment: Seems to me you need some kind of memory queuing mechanism and flush your queue in a background process. You can than write multiple rows at once instead of 1 row at the time.

Comment: A SQL database should be installed on a machine with the fastest speed, largest amount of memory, and as many Cores as possible.  Trying to run a database on a small machine is ludicrous

Comment: @jdweng Where does it say the database is on a small machine? Can you please, please, please read things properly before you reply.

Comment: Does each request you receive contain a single message? Because if so, then bulk insert isn't going to help you.

Comment: @DavidG : Where does it say that the database is on a large machine?  OPs usually do not give all the necessary info to solve an issue.  Bulk insert will quickly overload a machine that is too small.

Comment: @jdweng OP literally said the database can handle the load they need, so no, bulk insert won't overload anything here.

Comment: Last time we had to handle something like this, we shoved the burst of data into a RabbitMQ and then start a process that loaded data out of the queue into the DB. Redis could probably do similar for you or even a small in mem cache in the app

Comment: ..but really we need to know more about what operation you're actually performing. A straight insert of a "reasonable" number of columns should get easily get 4000 a second, but if you're doing an upsert then that'll whack speeds some. Bulk processing will be necessary to keep speeds up I dare say

Comment: *can't be queued* - a queueing solution that can consume 4000 messages a second is 3x faster than your best effort 1200/sec so far, so things must be backing up somewhere.. if you get 4000/sec for 10 secs it'll take you 33sec to chew through them as you are; that's already a queue. Don't shy away from a queueing solution "just because it's a queuing solution" - queueing may very well be faster than non queueing

Comment: This is Military Tactics in reverse.  Instead of Hurry Up and Wait.  The OP is using Wait and Hurry Up.  The code is waiting for bulk data and then trying to shove the data quickly into the database before next bulk data is ready and failing.   Efficiency doesn't matter if the algorithm doesn't work.  Making Bulk size smaller may help.  The code need to send data constantly to the database so code doesn't fall behind. What may work is a timer instead of waiting for fixed amount of data. Make sure data is constantly being send to database instead of having idle time where no data is being sent.

Comment: I would do some testing - and 100% by-pass EF. The idea that this provides much more security? Doubt it. EF has a LOT of overhead - in fact it is often HUGE, , and you might want to try using ado.net, data tables and directly hitting the database - you get a big increases in performance if you do this, but it still might not be enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies. I was finally able to sell them on a queue. As @jdweng said, "It's a Wait and Hurry up approach". In the end it's a queue with a bulk insert. It can easily handle the load and barely struggles with any amount of load.

Comment: You need to evenly process the data.  If you wait too long to fill up the queue before the bulk insert you end up falling behind and never catch up.  So you may need to make the queue size smaller or use a timer to send data at fixed intervals.  I think the real issue is the machine where database is located is too slow and/or doesn't have enough memory to keep up.